# PHP - Redirecting and including files from different directories

Tags: php, include, directory, web-hosting, include-path

So lets say I have this given directory

public_html

- home
- - user
- - - page1.php
- - register
- - - reg.php
- - page2.php
- css
- - general.css

index.php

Now lets say I want to include page2.php inside page1.php
i do this:

include "/home/page2.php";

But it doesn't work, the / is supposed to be the root directory (public_html).

or I want to redirect from reg.php to index.php

"/index.php" doesnt work.

Note: this is all on a hosting server.

Answer (score 4):

`/` is not the site root directory, it is the root directory of your OS's filesystem.

You can use a relative path modifier like so: `../../yourincludefile.php` to navigate upwards through the filesystem

Or you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to call the full path from the OS. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will offer you more consistent results and lets you include the same file no matter where in the directory hierarchy you're working.

For example, if you have `includes/functions.php`, you can use this anywhere, on any script and it will always include the correct file path:

`include_once($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] . "/includes/functions.php");`

or using the reference inside the string:

`include_once("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/includes/functions.php");`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use relative paths, ie:
 I want to include page2.php inside page1.php i do this:

```
include "../page2.php";
```

I want to redirect from reg.php to index.php

```
"../../index.php"
```

Or if you are talking about index.php inside public_html,

```
"../../../index.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - file-relative:

```
include("../path/to/file.php");
```

Option 2 - root relative

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include($root."/path/to/file.php");
```